# RoR decimal field with :precision => 10, :scale => 6 is not storing decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal, precision, bigdecimal

I have a decimal field that does not stores decimals, although the schema file says:

```
t.decimal  "kg", :precision => 10, :scale => 6
```

If I do:

```
(15,000 * 1,010)/1,000,000
```

which should be `15.15`

it will only show `15.00`

On DDBB:

```
BigDecimal:7fd4cc707300,'0.15E2',9(36)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're getting which I believe is `15` and not `15.15` is the way `Fixnum` division works.  If you want decimals in your result, you need to include decimals in your operands:

Example:

```
# Decimal on denominator
> (15000 * 1010)/1000000.0
=> 15.15

# or, on numerator
> (15000.0 * 1010)/1000000
=> 15.15
```

You could then use this value to store in your `kg` field.